# Can't see GPIB instrument using pyvisa but I can see it in NI MAX

Tags: python-2.7, gpib

I have a gpib instrument I'm trying to contorl with pyvisa.
I can see the instrument in NI MAX as "GPIB0::26::INSTR", but when
I try to get the instrument list using pyvisa it just comes up with "COM1"

Here is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
import visa 
inst_lsit = get_instruments_list()
print inst_list
```

Here is the output of the code:

['COM1']

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: (I haven't used pyvisa and don't know if it delegates to NI-VISA, but...and this isn't what you want to hear) _a VISA implementation is not obliged to return all—or any—available resources for any resource query._ I hope this doesn't apply to your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. At the time I was using a 64 bit version of python because I thought I might need it to do GPIB communication on my 64 bit Windows 7 operating system. But I ended up uninstalling the 64 bit python and going back to the 32 bit python. Once I reinstalled the 32 bit python I could see my GPIB instrument in the pyvisa instrument list again. The moral of the story is to use 32 bit versions of software whenever possible.